# Can we make a exception char in input type='number' in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input type=number and I want it to accept 'R' character as an exception. is there any way can a input with type = number can accept a character?

or any alternative that you can suggest

Comment: No, you need to use a text field. If you then want to restrict the input of the text field to a certain pattern (or patterns), then you could use a regular expression to control that, for example.

Comment: use regular expression with type="text"

Answer (score 0):

I made my own solution.

```
function alnumInput(exception, inpBx) {
  $(inpBx).on("input", function () {
    if (this.value.toUpperCase()[0] == exception) {
      this.value = exception;
    } else if (isNaN(parseFloat(this.value.slice(-1)))) {
      this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
    }
  });
}
```